# How to implement frames and commands on omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I'm working on a project evaluation of TSCH feature in 802.15.4. I don't know how to implement the Enhanced beacon and the request and confirm messages between nodes on omnet++.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a generic question. Generally I would look into the current codebase of INET (2.99 and later recommended) and would try to find similar features as a starting point.

Comment: Can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367118/creating-wirelesssensornetwork-on-omnet-using-mixim